# Pyspark group elements by column and creating dictionaries

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark Dataframe read from a csv file in this way:

```
df = ss.read \
     .format("csv") \
     .option("delimiter", ";") \
     .option("header", "false") \
     .option("inferSchema", "true") \
     .option("escape", "\"") \
     .option("multiline", "true") \
     .option("wholeFile", "true") \
     .load(file_path)
```

The Dataframe is like this one:

```
|cod_cli|article_name|rank|
|123    |art_1       |1   |
|123    |art_2       |2   |
|123    |art_3       |3   |
|456    |art_4       |1   |
|456    |art_5       |2   |
|456    |art_6       |3   |
```

I want to group the element by the column **cod_cli** and create multiple columns, one for each product in the grouped set, and as a value a dictionary key-value with the key as the column name and as a value the value related to that column name, like this:

```
|cod_cli|Product 1                  |Product 2                  |Product 3                  |
|123    |{cod_art : art_1, rank : 1}|{cod_art : art_2, rank : 2}|{cod_art : art_3, rank : 3}|
|456    |{cod_art : art_4, rank : 1}|{cod_art : art_5, rank : 2}|{cod_art : art_6, rank : 3}|
```

The dictionary value can be both a string (better) or a map.
I tried in this way:

```
df = df \
     .groupBy(F.col("cod_cli")) \
     .agg(F.collect_list(F.array("cod_art","rank")))
```

But in this way, I'm creating a column with an array column with all the grouped elements.

Please anyone can help me?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

The solution proposed is this one:

```
df = df.withColumn(
            "Product",
            F.to_json(
                F.struct(F.col("cod_art"), F.col("rank"))
            )
        )
```

In this way, I create a column "Product" with the json string desired, example `{cod_art : art_1, rank : 1}`.

Then:

```
df = df \
     .groupBy(F.col("cod_cli")) \
     .pivot("rank") \
     .agg(F.first("Product"))
```

In this way, I can create one column for each product, grouped by the **cod_cli** attribute, and handle situations in which I have more than 3 products as columns:

```
|cod_cli|1                          |2                          |3               
|123    |{cod_art : art_1, rank : 1}|{cod_art : art_2, rank : 2}|{cod_art : art_3, rank : 3}|
|456    |{cod_art : art_4, rank : 1}|{cod_art : art_5, rank : 2}|{cod_art : art_6, rank : 3}|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is useful-

### Load the data provided

```scala
 val data =
      """
        |cod_cli|article_name|rank
        |123    |art_1       |1
        |123    |art_2       |2
        |123    |art_3       |3
        |456    |art_4       |1
        |456    |art_5       |2
        |456    |art_6       |3
      """.stripMargin
    val stringDS = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
            .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS)

    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +-------+------------+----+
      * |cod_cli|article_name|rank|
      * +-------+------------+----+
      * |123    |art_1       |1   |
      * |123    |art_2       |2   |
      * |123    |art_3       |3   |
      * |456    |art_4       |1   |
      * |456    |art_5       |2   |
      * |456    |art_6       |3   |
      * +-------+------------+----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- cod_cli: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- article_name: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- rank: integer (nullable = true)
      */
```

#### Create columns as specified using `pivot` and `first` (should be implemented in pyspark with minimal changes all are `pyspark.sql.functions`)

```scala
    df.groupBy("cod_cli")
      .pivot("rank")
      .agg(first("article_name"))
      .select($"cod_cli", $"1".as("Product 1"), $"2".as("Product 2"), $"3".as("Product 3"))
      .withColumn("Product 1", to_json(expr("named_struct('cod_art', `Product 1`, 'rank', '1')")))
      .withColumn("Product 2", to_json(expr("named_struct('cod_art', `Product 2`, 'rank', '2')")))
      .withColumn("Product 3", to_json(expr("named_struct('cod_art', `Product 3`, 'rank', '3')")))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
      * |cod_cli|Product 1                     |Product 2                     |Product 3                     |
      * +-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
      * |123    |{"cod_art":"art_1","rank":"1"}|{"cod_art":"art_2","rank":"2"}|{"cod_art":"art_3","rank":"3"}|
      * |456    |{"cod_art":"art_4","rank":"1"}|{"cod_art":"art_5","rank":"2"}|{"cod_art":"art_6","rank":"3"}|
      * +-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
      */
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I followed your solution in order to improve my solution and make it more dynamic (it's possible that the number of "Product" is not defined). I updated the original message

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without **`pivot`**(*expensive operation*), using **`collect_list`** of **`struct`**, then **`to_json`** with **`create_map`**.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df\
  .groupBy("cod_cli").agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("article_name","rank"))\
                          .alias("arr"))\
  .select("cod_cli", *(F.to_json(F.create_map(F.lit("cod_art"),(F.col("arr.article_name")[x]),F.lit("rank"),(F.col("arr.rank")[x])))\
                       .alias("Product{}".format(x+1)) for x in range(3)))\
  .show(truncate=False)

#+-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
#|cod_cli|Product1                      |Product2                      |Product3                      |
#+-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
#|123    |{"cod_art":"art_1","rank":"1"}|{"cod_art":"art_2","rank":"2"}|{"cod_art":"art_3","rank":"3"}|
#|456    |{"cod_art":"art_4","rank":"1"}|{"cod_art":"art_5","rank":"2"}|{"cod_art":"art_6","rank":"3"}|
#+-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```